# Where could shortcuts for Git be defined?

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I am running in some weird issues on my mac Git setup. I seem to have shortcuts defined for GC, GD etc:

```
➜  ~  where gc
gc: aliased to git commit -v
```

I am using oh-my-zsh, and I have looked in my .zshrc, and my .gitconfig for alias definitions. However, these GC, GD aliases are nowhere to be found.

any clues?

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but it seems like these are shipped out-of-the-box with oh-my-zsh. https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet via a plugin. You might be able to remove the plugin by looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/.

Comment: don't know about osx, but what is the output of `git config -l`? also, if nothing in local .gitconfig, check /etc/gitconfig

Answer (score 2):

They are defined inside oh-my-zsh in the git plugin: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh